# Related Independent Events (2.5.24)

Tags: probability, independence

Please verify my solution to this problem.

> Each of *m* urns contains three red chips and four white chips. A total of *r* samples with replacement are taken from each urn. What is the probability that at least one red chip is drawn from at least one urn?

Here is my solution:

$P$(at least one red chip is drawn from at least one urn)$=$
$1-P$(no red chip is drawn from any urn)$=$
$1-P$(only white chips are drawn from the urns)$=$
There is a $\tfrac47$ chance of drawing a white chip out of any one of the *m* urns.
Since it is replaced, there is an $(\frac47)^{r}$ chance of drawing a white chip for each of the *r* draws from any urn.
Therefore, $P$(draw at least one red chip from at least one urn) $=$  $1-(\frac47)^{m*r}$

Comment: Where's your solution?

Comment: It is very difficult to verify invisible solutions

Comment: I'm new to the site. Now I realize that my solution is included in the question, not as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your working is fine.

The complement event is we do not see any red chips, which means that we only get white chips in all of the $m\cdot r$ trials.

Hence, the answer is $$1-\left( \frac47\right)^{m\cdot r}$$

Comment: Thanks for feedback!